# Trigger event only on specific div when mouse is over

Tags: jquery, animation

I have six list items and I want to animate the single item only on mouse over.

This is my snippet:

```
  <li>
    <div class="overview top_out">Eye</div>
    <div class="link bottom_out">link</div>
    <div class="image"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="overview top_out">Eye</div>
    <div class="link bottom_out">link</div>
    <div class="image"></div>
  </li>
  // other same list items
```

What I trying to do is to remove the "top_out" class when mouse in over the list item.

I tried this:

```
$("ul li").hover(function(){
    $(".overview").toggleClass("top_out");
});
```

but what I obtained is that all divs react together.

How can I do this?

Here an example of what to obtain (section Portfolio): [Esample site](http://sftheme.com/demos/onewp/#welcome)
I want the same icon animation effect

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use the hovered over `li` as the context:

```
$("ul li").hover(function(){
    $(".overview", this).toggleClass("top_out");
});
```

Rather than `.hover(function() ...` you may want to use:

```
.on('mouseenter mouseleave', function() ...
```

```js
$("ul li").on('mouseenter mouseleave', function(){
    $(".overview", this).toggleClass("top_out");
});
```

```css
.top_out {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
<li>
    <div class="overview top_out">Eye</div>
    <div class="link bottom_out">link</div>
    <div class="image"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="overview top_out">Eye</div>
    <div class="link bottom_out">link</div>
    <div class="image"></div>
  </li>
  </ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
$('ul li').on('mouseenter mouseleave', function() {
        $(this).find('.overview').toggleClass('top_out');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you need to toggle the class based on the context of the element you are hovering over.

Use the jQuery selector `$(".overview", this)` to select `.overview` elements within the `li` element that is currently being moused over.

I also change the `hover` event to `mouseover`/`mouseout`.

```
$("ul li").on('mouseover mouseout', function () {
    $(".overview", this).toggleClass("top_out");
});
```

Which is essentially equivalent to

```
$("ul li").on('mouseover mouseout', function () {
    $(this).find(".overview").toggleClass("top_out");
});
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried to write the this: $(this, ".overview").toggleClass("top_out"); and I hadn't think to put "this" after.

Comment: @Daniele You should accept [PeterKA's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28972849/2680216) since he answered first.

Comment: Just for curiosity: why do you suggest me to change from "hover" to your solution?